# Удаление из списка элементов больше 5

Tags: python

Пытаюсь удалить из списка все элементы больше 5, но почему-то код не работает.

```
foo = [2, 18, 9, 22, 17, 24, 8, 12, 27]
for i in foo:
    if i > 5:
        foo.remove(i)
print(foo)
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: функция remove принимает номер позиции элемента, который надо удалить, а не значение элемента.

Comment: и удаление в цикле по живому foo не очень хорошая идея

Comment: @Chorkov Кстати, нет. Не в этом дело, а в том, что итерация ломается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще создать отфильтрованный список

```
bar = [x for x in foo if x <= 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Много раз этот вопрос тут обсуждался. Удаление элементов из списка, по которому вы итерируетесь, ломает итерацию, она "проскакивает" элементы, следующие за удаляемыми. Одно из простых решений - итерироваться по копии списка:

```py
for i in foo.copy():
            ^^^^^^^
```

Но более питонично всё же формировать новый список, фильтруя элементы.